# I need the command , which will act exactly as Translate command in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need to scramble the data as per below , if one of the person name is 
William , the output should be Jihhiar. It can be done using the Translate command in oracle sql. But the SQL server the translate command is not compatible.

Hence require help to identify the exact function for Translate in sql server.

Comment: What do you mean by _translate command is not compatible_?

Answer (score 0):

Use **REPLACE**

```
select REPLACE(TableName.PersonName, 'William', 'Jihhiar')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you say [`TRANSLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) doesn't work:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('William','Wlm','Jhr');
```

The provides the value 'Jihhiar'`.

Comment: Most likely because he isn't on SQL 2017, or with old compatibility level :)

Comment: *"Not Compatible"* doesn't really imply that. It suggests the functionality of it iosn't correct. If they don't have access to it, then why didn't they state "I am not using SQL Server 2017, so cannot use `TRANSLATE`" instead of using very vague wording?